# Check if a process is already running on a server

Tags: python, linux, process, cron

I own a server that I want to run a Python (2.7) threaded server script on it.

I have a cron job that validates every minute that the script is up and running, if it is, let it continue do it's work, else launch it.

I have searched and found several solutions to make this check work, but none of the solutions I found seem to work.

The Python script that I want to ALWAYS run on the server is called **"serverListener.py"**

So what happens, the cron job runs the script **wd.sh** which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
python /home2/ofekafsc/public_html/cgi-bin/wd.py
```

Now, the script **wd.py** has a solution in which I tried to use, but I never receive **true**.

I am trying to check whether the process is running, if so do nothing, else launch it. The problem I have is it ALWAYS returns FALSE (as for the server is NOT running)

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import psutil

def running3(program, scriptname):
    for pid in psutil.pids(): # Iterates over all process-ID's found by psutil,
        try:
            p = psutil.Process(pid) 
            if program in p.name(): 
                for arg in p.cmdline():
                    if scriptname in str(arg):  
                        return True
                    else:
                        pass
            else:
                pass
            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    f = open("/home2/ofekafsc/public_html/cgi-bin/ERRORLOG.txt", "w+")
                    f.write(str(e))
                    f.close()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(str(e))
if(running3("python", "serverListener.py")):
    print("RUNNING")
    sys.exit()
else:
    subprocess.call("/home2/ofekafsc/public_html/cgi-bin/serverListener.py")
```

As mentioned, the above code did not do the job.

This is what the loop finds:

```
Program name : python
arg in cmdline: python
arg in cmdline: /home2/ofekafsc/public_html/cgi-bin/wd.py
```

It does not find the `serverListener.py` script, even though it is launched for the first time from this script.

I think it might have something to do with Users and Permissions at the server, but since I never call the script manually, I don't see a reason for that to be the problem.

Any help will be gratefully received.

Comment: have you printed the returned values for each process? at least the names.

Comment: you should fix your indentation, broken in the first snippet (for/try in the same alignment)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it finds "python" as the name,
and indentations fixed

Comment: can you show the shebang of `/home2/ofekafsc/public_html/cgi-bin/serverListener.py` ? cannot reproduce your issue here, on windows. Works fine

Comment: Works fine on windows

Comment: If it always returns false, then one of the ifs doesn't do its job. First step would be to figure out which step that is, then take it from there.

Comment: when it finds "python", try to print `p.cmdline()`. And why `str(arg)` and not just `arg`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The shebang is #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre (program ) python (arg) /home2/ofekafsc/public_html/cgi-bin/wd.py (By the script's vars)

Comment: `except:
            continue` is a very bad practice. better not catch any exception, or catch with `except Exception as e: print(str(e))`

Comment: I bet that you're getting an exception, but since you "continue" when you get it, you don't see it

Comment: are you starting `/home2/ofekafsc/public_html/cgi-bin/serverListener.py` manually from another process/script ?

Comment: Since this is running on a server , in which I am not connected through ssh, I cannot visually see exceptions, I let it write exceptions into a log file that has not been created yet so no exception raised. The `/home2/ofekafsc/public_html/cgi-bin/serverListener.py` script is being called from `wp.py` and not manually

Comment: On a somewhat unrelated note, `else: pass` is really unnecessary.  If there's nothing you need to do for `else`, don't need to include it.